# How to transform multiple tables in one excel sheet to one table with Power BI?

Tags: pivot, powerbi, transform, unpivot

I would like to transfer this humanly readable table either into one long table, for example through an "Attribute" Column which then includes "Category A" and "Category B" or I would like to split them into multiple sheets within PowerBI. The "delimiter" is always a empty column.

[image: Multiple Tables in one sheet]

Answer (score 1):

If I guess correct-

1. You have single spread sheet with data belongs to multiple category.
2. You wants to load whole data to Power BI
3. But you need separate sheet per category.

You can perform these following steps to achieve your required data sets in Power BI-

1. load the sheet to power bi
2. duplicate your data set as many time you wants number of data set
3. Go through all data sets and remove all columns except columns you required in current data set.

This should give you your desired data sets in power bi.